# What is the frequency domain equation of my time domain equation?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

I am trying to apply Laplace transformation to my cost model in order to use a PI controller in the future. If I understood correctly I have to transform my time-domain functions to the frequency-domain (or S domain). My proportional gain is given by the time-domain function as:

L<sub>relative</sub> = λ<sub>current</sub> / λ<sub>minimal</sub>

where, λ = is the throughput of my system, and L is the parameter used to get an equilibrium among all λ. I use the function above to change the parameter L. The table below exemplifies the function with data.

[image]

How do I convert this function to the frequency domain or take the [Laplace transform of this equation](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=ControlPID)? What are the steps? Could you please explain in a stepwise?

I guess I have to use the Laplace transform $\frac{1}{a} \times x(t)$, because it is similar to my function. But how do I transform my time-domain function to a frequency-domain function?

Thanks

Comment: So do you know how $th_{\text{current}}$ and $th_{\text{minimal}}$ depend on time? Do you have some data of it or how does it work?

Comment: I added my table of values and I changed $th$ to $λ$.

Comment: Hi @MattiP. any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'll pass on trying to interpret all those numbers, thanks. Good luck on your journey!

Comment: ok. thanks anyway...